# Redefining a block initially defined in an included view in the parent view with twig

Tags: symfony, include, block, twig, extends

I have a view A that includes a view B that defines a block Z. Can I have a view C that extends A and redefines block Z?

Need not be said that if i paste B into A (without using an include) it works.

For a practical example:

A is the base of a project.
B is the header of a project that includes a menu.
C is any page of the project.

I define a {% block active %}{% endblock %} for each item of the menu in B, that i want to redefine by {% block active %} class="active" {% endblock %} in C to apply certain styles to the current active menu item.

If this is not the way to go, which is the best workaround/solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible or it wouldn't be as easy.

Why not bind a variable to the template from the controller and passing it to the nav through the include?

```
{% include MyAwesomeBundle:Modules:nav.html.twig with {activeItem: activeItem, activeItemClassName: activeItemClassName} %}
```

An alternative to what you want

```
{# in base layout template #}
{% block nav %}
    {% include MyAwesomeBundle:Modules:nav.html.twig %}
{% endblock %}

{# in page template #}
{% extends base-layout.html.twig %}

{% block nav %}
    {% include MyAwesomeBundle:Modules:nav_for_news.html.twig %} {# nav_for_news.html.twig extends nav.html.twig #}
{% endblock %}
```

This is the closest you can get from what you want

Check out the [parent() twig function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/parent.html) it's useful.

Comment: i ended up doing it similarly to your first suggestion, eventhough i was not very happy because i get extra variables in the controller, thanks!

Comment: You could make your nav aware of the route by using `{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}` in Twig; that would work too